# android videoView not loading uri video

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

hi am trying to play a video from my web server in a video view, the code worked perfectly with my previous server however it is giving me a no content provider error when trying to play from the new server. i don't know what the problem is i doesn’t look like the access is been restricted because if i type the destination in a browser the both allow me to download

```
     final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.profileVid);

     String ondPath = "http://www.gogodis.comxa.com/img/1/profileVid/SampleVideo.3gp";
     String newPath = "http://www.reelychat.com/img/1/profileVid/SampleVideo.3gp";

                try {
                    // Start the MediaController
                    MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(ProfileN.this);
                    mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
                    // Get the URL from String VideoURL
                    Uri video = Uri.parse(newPath);
                    videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
                    videoview.setVideoURI(video);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                videoview.requestFocus();
                videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    // Close the progress bar and play the video
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        videoview.start();
                    }
                });
```

and here is a copy of the logcast

```
07-26 15:13:36.097 27979-27979/com.reallyChat D/MediaPlayer: setDataSource IOException happend : 
                                                         java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://www.reelychat.com/img/1/profileVid/SampleVideo.3gp
                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:713)
                                                             at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:617)
                                                             at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:954)
                                                             at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:236)
                                                             at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:198)
                                                             at android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(VideoView.java:188)
                                                             at com.really_chat.ProfileN$DownloadWebpageTask.onPostExecute(ProfileN.java:722)
                                                             at com.really_chat.ProfileN$DownloadWebpageTask.onPostExecute(ProfileN.java:628)
                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                             at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help

Comment: Are you using the same device to try from new and old server? Did you set android.permission.INTERNET permission?

Comment: @OlsiSaqe yes same device and the permissions are set

Comment: Can you also register a listener with setOnErrorListener() that might give you more info on why it's failing?

Comment: @OlsiSaqe thanks for getting back to me please would you mind giving an example of how to implement the setOnErrorListener() as in what value to print out to show the error